# Sci-fi novel with prisoner trying to escape a prison on another planet. Has a romance with the warden's concubine. They escape by hovercraft

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a book I read back in the 80's about a guy who gets in trouble and is sent to a distant planet that's super hostile with a prison.

There's a concubine (essentially the warden's sex slave; she's a prisoner), a bodybuilder woman I think who's called Raze, and some martial arts expert who I think his name is Sandoz or something.

Somehow the hero builds some kind of device he uses to warp into other parts of the prison and helps his new crew escape using the warden's personal hovercraft. They divide into two hostile groups and fight for control of a ship that can take them off planet while being pursued by the warden etc.

It's a romance between the hero and the sex slave woman too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Omega Cage](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2624) by Steve Perry.

> Sentenced for a crime he didn't commit, Dain Maro has been incarcerated in the Omega Cage--a prison located on an isolated planet and housing the scum of the galaxy. Escape was supposed to be impossible, but the Omega Cage has never had to contain the likes of Dain Maro before.

The bodybuilder is called Raze. She is from a heavy gravity world called Tatsu, which is why she is so strong.

> Behind him, a voice said, "The woman you've been admiring is called Raze.
> She's from Tatsu, just like Lepto. It's a heavy-gravity world."
> ...
> "High-gee or not," he said, "she's strong." He looked back at Scanner. "A mue?"
> Scanner looked back at Raze and smiled slightly. "Not exactly, though she's had
> a few genes spliced. But the primary trick is forced superdense musculature
> growth, alloy-reinforced bone structure, and nylon ligaments. She can probably
> punch through steel."

The martial arts expert is indeed called Sandoz.

> Scanner shook his head. "One more. Sandoz."
> "More mind games?"
> "No. Sandoz is nothing if not physical."
> Maro spun in a small circle, searching the yard, feeling for danger, looking for
> someone who carried himself or herself in a way that suggested more than usual
> competence. He was fairly good with his hands and feet—close combat was
> taught by the Melders as part of body control— but he wasn't good enough to do
> more than slow a real expert, without surprise on his side. But they had also
> taught him how to recognize a real expert. Look for balance, for centeredness,
> for confidence, open your senses and feel the ki. You can sense it, if it is
> powerful enough.
> There. There he was. A tall man, well-built but not like a bodybuilder, looking away from Maro.

The warden's concubine is Juete:

> "Juete ... The albino."
> "You saw her?"
> Maro nodded. "I saw her."
> Scanner laughed. "She's an Exotic, from the Dark world. Genetic playtoys,
> originally, but they bred true. Pheromonically potent and designed to attract anything remotely human, male or female. You felt her pull, I take it?"

And finally Dain Moro does indeed escape in a hovercraft.

Comment: Thank you so very much!!!!